# calculate triangle shade from angle between normal and camera vector

Tags: python, vector, colors, 3d, rendering

I am currently trying to better understand 3d graphics. My goal is to get a value between 0 and 255 to shade a triangle. I have 2 vectors (as tuples): the normal of a triangle and the camera vector. I can calculate the angle between them with:

```
def calcAngleBetweenVectors(v1, v2):
    return math.acos(dot(v1, v2) / (calcVectorMagnitude(v1) * calcVectorMagnitude(v2))) * 180 / math.pi

def dot(v1, v2):  # Dotproduct
    return v1[0] * v2[0] + v1[1] * v2[1] + v1[2] * v2[2]

def calcVectorMagnitude(v):
    return math.sqrt(v[0] * v[0] + v[1] * v[1] + v[2] * v[2])
```

eg.:

```
print(calcAngleBetweenVectors((10, 15, 0), (1, 2, 3)))
```

How can I go from the angle to a grayscale value? I have tried several things like:

```
angle / 180 * 255
```

But that doesn't seam to work. I use Python, but all help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is a horrible solution but this is what I came up with:

```
def mapValue(value, start1, stop1, start2,
                stop2):  # Maps a value from a range ont a nother value from a different range
    return start2 + (stop2 - start2) * ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1))

if a <= 95:
    shade = round(mapValue(a, 95, 0, 255, 0))
    drawTriangle(triangle, shade)
else:
    shade = round(mapValue(a, 180, 95, 255, 0))
    drawTriangle(triangle, shade)
```

I know its bad, so if you know how to improve this please go ahead.